# Firebase Realtime Database - how to structure initial load and listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I am writing a application in React-Redux with Firebase Realtime database for storage and wish load initial data while also receiving updates when data changes. The desired data workflow would be:

1. Load initial data from Firebase Realtime Database
2. Populate Redux Store and load UI
3. Receive database update from Firebase Realtime Database
4. Update Redux store and components

What I have completed so far is step 1 and 2, now I am considering what is best practice for data update on database change.

In my present code I call a series of api functions to retrieve the inital data.

```
const setInitialStore = () => {
  return dispatch => Promise.all([
    dispatch(startSetUser()),
    dispatch(startSetNotes()),
    ...
  ])
}

//** ACTION ***
export const setNotes = (notes) => ({
  type: SET_NOTES,
  notes
})
//async action, fetch data and dispatches SET_NOTES
export const startSetNotes = () => {
  //thunk gives access to store-methods dispatch and getState
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const apiInstruction = { action: DB_ACTION_GET_SUBSCRIBE, payload: null, uid: getState().auth.uid }
    //returns a promise
    return noteAPI(apiInstruction)
      .then((notes) => {
        //get data into redux
        dispatch(setNotes(notes))
    })
  }
}

//** REDUCER
const notesReducerDefaultState = []
const notesReducer = (state = notesReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NOTES:
      //returning new array, don't care about what's instate
      return action.notes;
    ...
  }
}

//** noteAPI - action "DB_ACTION_GET_SUBSCRIBE" section ***
database.ref(`${dbPath}`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const notes = []
  //parse data
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const note = {
      id: childSnapshot.key,
      ...childSnapshot.val()
    }
    const noteModel = new NoteModel(note, uid)
    notes.push(noteModel.reduxStoreObj)
  })
  //return notes
  resolve(notes)
})
```

The above code structure explained below.

```
setInitialStore - dispatches the action from "setNote"
  startSetNote - calls the API that fetches data for action generator
    noteAPI - Calls Firebase Realtime Database ".on()" and returns all notes
      setNote - Action generator called with collection from database
```

This approach has one crucial flaw though - when the Firebase Realtime Database updates the store will not get updated. :( 
The listener only triggers inside the noteAPI and therefore never gets dispatched to the store.

What would the recommended best practice be for fetching and updating data? 
Should I only fetch initial data with ".once()" and then write separate code to handle listeners with ".once()"? In that case where would that code "live"?

In other words - how can I structure my code so that the Firebase Realtime Database listener updates the Redux store automatically?

I have read the documentation on read and writes. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write